# Is there any possibility to align to the screen center the second element of a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Row with three elements. I want to have the second element right in the middle of the space occupied by the row and not depending on the first element of the row. I've tried like this but seems that the _buildLogo widget is center align between the end of first element and the starting point of the third element.

```
 child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildCancelButton(),
            _buildLogo(),
            _buildExtraText(),
          ],
        ),
```

I've also tried with a Stack/Row combination but then I have problems with the vertical alignment.

```
child: Stack(
    children: [
      _buildLogo(),
      Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildCancelButton(),
            _buildExtraText(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
```

I will attach a picture with my result. [image]

Adding Spacer() between the _buildLogo() will lead with the same result.

```
 _buildCancelButton(),
 Spacer(),
 _buildLogo(),
 Spacer(),
  _buildExtraText(),
```

[image]

Comment: Consider explaining your question properly

Comment: can you please show vertical alignment issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your logo actually is in the middle, but it kind a looks a little bit off, because of the icon on the left side. Maybe a 'dumb' beginner-solution is adding some sapces after the 'AirDolomiti'-text (like this: 'AirDolomiti    ').

Did this help or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: I've tried with the spacer, like @Faiizii suggested but I get the same result. Adding only one Spacer will, of course, fill the entire space between the logo and the third widget with all the space available.

Comment: he is asking for adding white-space at the end of your text (not about using spacer ).

Comment: Actually the entire air dolomiti is a logo image so no space can be added to that :)

Comment: @FlorinLaudat yes I ment the white-space. Oh I thought it's a text. Isn there another way to 'add' invisible space on the right side to manage this problem. As there is no snippet for the _buildLogo() I can't really help. Sorry

Comment: Probably I will add some right padding to the logo image. The _buildLogo is actually just an Image.network wrapped into a Container with a fix height. My problem with the right padding is that the Cancel text (first widget) can vary depending on the system language. But let's say the customer will close the eyes on some pixels align..

Comment: What happens if you change to mainaxisalignment.top in the stackversion?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spacer()`. It will align your 2nd widget in center.

```
child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildCancelButton(),
         Spacer(), //add it here
        _buildLogo(),
         Spacer(), // add it here
        _buildExtraText(),
      ],
    ),
```

**Note:** the `buildLogo`'s horizontal alignment will depend on first and third widget's width

Comment: Thank you for the hint. My problem is that the first and the third widgets are having different width so the Spacer will not help too much. Related to the minor pixel difference it's not depending on me, is depending on the customer ;).

Comment: did you try the solution ? I give it a try and second widget exactly centered.

Comment: yes, of course :). There is still a difference. I will add a picture with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If Left and right widget are same size then the middle widget will be in center. So make it equal, use sizedbox.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. The texts and the third widget are fill in a dynamic way so the values can be change (depending on language, on the API response etc).

Comment: Then before showing the widgets, calculate the width of dynamic data